# Method returns runnable object

Tags: java, thread-safety, runnable

Can I do something like this in Java:

```
 protected Runnable getRunnable(final int seconds) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                sendData();             
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
        }
    };
    return runnable;
}
```

And then:

```
protected void startTimer(int seconds) throws InterruptedException,NullPointerException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(getRunnable(seconds));
    thread.start();
}
```

Is the aforementioned process safe??

Comment: "Is the aforementioned process safe??" => from what perspective? There is no shared state or variable in the code you show so it is thread safe. However the `sendData` method might not be...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no point having a thread sleep as the last thing it does.  Did you mean to delay the sending, or can the sleep be dropped?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to execute sendData() method every a specific amount of seconds(i.e. every 15 seconds). I introduce in order to succeed this a while(true) loop below the void run method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments you say

> All I'm trying to do is to execute sendData() method every a specific amount of seconds(i.e. every 15 seconds)

Then use a built-in Timer which will organise that for you, for example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendData();
    }
};
ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//when you want to cancel the scheduled task
future.cancel(true);

//and before you leave your program, don't forget to call:
scheduler.shutdown();
```

Comment: Nice answer. By the way, if I want to stop the aforementioned how can I do it? I mean that this will run every 15 seconds(and forever). How can I interrupt the thread?

Comment: @AlexDowining By cancelling the returned Future - see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is safe (assuming `sendData` itself is safe), but I'm not sure exactly what you expect it to do.  Your code as written will create a new thread that will immediately call `sendData()`, then after `sendData` returns the thread will sleep for a number of seconds and then terminate without doing anything else (so the sleep is pointless, other than preventing the JVM from exiting or the `Runnable` or its containing object from being garbage collected until the sleep is finished).  If you want it to wait *before* calling `sendData` then you need to swap things around a bit.

Comment: Since I think that's what the question is about, it's worth stressing the point that `sendData` has to be threadsafe. The current implementation easily allows someone to obtain loads of `Runnables` with `getRunnable` and then start all of them in immediate succession. If `sendData` isn't careful with what it does, all hell will break loose...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it ? The answer is that it does work. `Runnable` is an interface implemented by an `Object` (an anonymous class in your example above), and you can pass it around / reference it just like any other object.

Note that because the above is an inner class, you'll have an *implicit* reference to the outer (surrounding) class.

Comment: As the question is tagged "thread-safety" I'm not sure the question was about whether an anonymous class implementing Runnable can be created. But maybe it was...

Comment: It seems to work. However, I'm noob and I afraid threads. And from the little experience that I have, I realised that with the Threads you never know!